# How can I compare two text files line by line and print error if not matched?

Tags: perl

Let me briefly go through what I trying to do, as now my script is pulling files from SFTP to local system. To ensure the files is not corrupted while pulling. So I need to make sure the `file size` is exactly the same. After the files pulled from SFTP,I print out the `file size` and `filename` to a `filename.txt` as below. I do this is because I try to compare this two text files to ensure no files is corrupted.

**Filename.txt**

```
7 hankeong_test.txt
3 hankeong_test2.txt
10753 hankeong_test3.txt
```

However, SFTP command is limited. It can't only display `Size` and `File name`, the only command i can use is `ls -l *.txt`.Below is the output from SFTP to `input.txt`.

**input.txt**

```
-rwxr-xr-x     512      501             7 Jul 24 17:54 hankeong_test.txt
-rwxr-xr-x     512      501             3 Jul 25 11:32 hankeong_test2.txt
-rwxr-xr-x     512      501         10753 Jul 24 17:54 hankeong_test3.txt
sftp> ls -l *.txt
sftp> quit
```

How can I compare this two files while they having two different format?

Expected Output:

The code can compare two files line by line and to see whether the line is correct, if incorrect it will print out `ERROR` message to user.

I am using Windows 7 and SSH tectia to access to the SFTP.

Any advise or other better solution to share? Thanks!

Comment: have you considered using diff

Comment: It would be worth mentioning in your question what operating system you are using locally and what methods of accessing the remote system are available to you. Judging from your earlier screenshots, it appeared that you were running Windows on your local machine.

Comment: @TomFenech sorry for the late reply, due to timezone. I am using Windows 7 and SSH tectia to access to the SFTP.

Comment: @RussHyde Nop, I still new in perl thats why I do not know much about it yet. I will take a look on diff. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, parsing `ls` is not considered to be a good idea: see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls), for example. That said, you could use something like this to compare the two lists:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($files, $ls) = ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]);
open my $fh_files, "<", $files;
open my $fh_ls, "<", $ls;

my %sizes;
while (<$fh_files>) {    
    # regex assumes filenames contain no spaces
    if (my ($size, $name) = /^(\d+)\s+(\S+)$/) {
        $sizes{$name} = $size;
    }
}

while(<$fh_ls>) {
    # if output is tab-delimited, use split /\t/
    my @cols = split;
    my ($size, $name) = ($cols[3], $cols[7]);

    if (!defined $sizes{$name}) { 
        print "$name: file exists locally but not on device\n";
    }
    elsif ($sizes{$name} != $size) {
        print "$name has incorrect size\n";
        print "size on host: $size\n";
        print "local size: $sizes{$name}\n";
    }
}

close $fh_files;
close $fh_ls;
```

Use it like: `perl filelist_compare.pl Filename.txt input.txt`

Comment: Thanks Tom, seem like this is the only solution I manage to understood and this is exactly same as what I trying to do. Thanks! Salute for you o.o\ !

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two better ways:

1. Instead of SFTP, use `rsync` to transfer and check that the local and remote files are identical.
2. Perform the transfer using some Perl module for SFTP (for instance, [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign)). You will be able to handle transmission errors when they happen and also query the remote file system easily.

Comment: Agreed that either of these two approaches would be preferable. Perhaps some example of how you might do the transfer in Perl would be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Dare I mention using MD5 or SHA hashes or the unix sum command to ascertain the validity of the files?

Comment: Comparing hashes sounds like a good idea. Perhaps you could provide the OP with some idea of how they might go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an md5 digest of the files rather than the file size. If you have sftp access, you may also have ssh access. If so, try the following on the remote server and the same locally. Save the output in two files then compare with `diff`:

```
openssl md5 *.txt
MD5(hankeong_test.txt)= 0bee89b07a248e27c83fc3d5951213c1
MD5(hankeong_test2.txt)= 614dd0e977becb4c6f7fa99e64549b12
MD5(hankeong_test3.txt)= b6273b589df2dfdbd8fe35b1011e3183
```